# Pass a boolean to JPA native query in Oracle DBMS

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a quite complicated query running with JPA for my Orcale DBMS, and I need to pass boolean, let say:

```
@Query(SELECT id FROM Person where :myCondition AND name='Alex', nativeQuery = true)
Set<Long> findPersonIds(@Param("myCondition") boolean myCondition);
```

So, for now I just converted my java-bool to int in static method (1=true, 0=false) to make raw booleans become expressions like

```
private static int boolToNum(boolean bool) { return bool ? 1 : 0; }

...
@Query(SELECT id FROM Person where 1=:myConditionNum AND name='Alex', nativeQuery = true)
Set<Long> findPersonIds(@Param("myConditionNum") boolean myConditionNum);
```

Are there any best practices to solve such issue in better way?

Comment: Your current approach is valid and reasonable; I wouldn't think to change it.